# Did Newton derive Titius-Bode Law of the planets in his Principia?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, history, planets

In college I was taught that no one knows why the planetary orbits conform to the [Titius-Bode Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titius%E2%80%93Bode_law).

Recently I read that Newton HAD figured that out in his Principia.

Right Now I can’t even find a reference to the equation, much less Newton’s derivation.

Can someone point me to a discussion of the Titius-Bode Law and/or Newton’s derivation of such or refutation of?

Comment: Where did you read that Newton derived the Titius-Bode law? I'm quite sure he didn't.

Comment: @Qmechanic  Thanks, it helps alot to have the correct name.

Comment: @Thomas Fritsch  Unfortunately I don’t remember, but it was news to me too which is why I asked if I was missing something.

Comment: This would probably better suit [HSM SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com), but [even today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titius%E2%80%93Bode_law#Theoretical_explanations) we don't fully understand the issue.